# Get all subordinates who directly or indirectly reports to supervisor with parameter supervisor

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to get all subordinate who direct and next direct subordinate with parameter supervisor Id.

I have a table

EmployeeId int, SupervisorId int

Sample Data :

```
    EmployeeId | SupervisorId 
    ----------------------
    1          | 4
    2          | 4
    4          | 6
    5          | 4
    7          | 6
    8          | 6
    ----------------------
```

My Parameter is Supervisor 6 and i want to get direct and indirect subordinate.

LINQ or MSSQL Query is accepted. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: How can an employee have a supervisor with ID=6 when there's no employee with an ID=6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to sql recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072166/linq-to-sql-recursive-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 declare @employeeId as integer = 706
 declare @EmployeeList table
 (
       EmployeeId int
 )
 declare @EmployeeList1 table
 (
       EmployeeId int
 )

 insert into @EmployeeList1
 select EmployeeId
 from Employee
 where ImmediateSupervisorId = @employeeId
 order by 1 

 insert into @EmployeeList
 select EmployeeId
 from Employee
 where ImmediateSupervisorId in (select employeeId from @EmployeeList1)

 select EmployeeId
 from Employees

 where (sr.ImmediateSupervisorId in (select employeeId from @EmployeeList)              
or sr.ImmediateSupervisorId = @employeeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could do it this way:

```
SELECT EmployeeID FROM myTable
WHERE SupervisorID IN (SELECT EmployeeID 
                       FROM myTable 
                       WHERE SupervisorID = 6)
OR SupervisorID = 6;
```

I don't know how to represent this as a LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all the employees that are downstream from a given supervisor?
If so, and if you are okay with going a maximum of 9 levels down, this would work (although it's crude).

```
    SELECT e.* FROM Employee e
        LEFT JOIN Employee s1 ON s1.EmployeeID = e.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s2 ON s2.EmployeeID = s1.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s3 ON s3.EmployeeID = s2.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s4 ON s4.EmployeeID = s3.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s5 ON s5.EmployeeID = s4.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s6 ON s6.EmployeeID = s5.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s7 ON s7.EmployeeID = s6.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s8 ON s8.EmployeeID = s7.SupervisorId
        LEFT JOIN Employee s9 ON s9.EmployeeID = s8.SupervisorId
    WHERE
        e.SupervisorID = 6
        OR ISNULL(s2.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s3.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s4.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s5.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s6.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s7.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s8.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
        OR ISNULL(s9.EmployeeId, 0) = 6
```

(Note that this will only work if the supervisor is himself in the table.)

Comment: It didnt work ash and i think this query is very slow but thanks for your answer. :)